# Not able to read "\" from an array

Tags: python, eol

I want to search and replace the string "\" from the array 'abc' in python code.

I'm using the following code

```
abc=re.sub("\"," ",abc)
```

But it is giving the following error

```
   File "script", line 99
    line_map=re.sub("\"," ",line_map)
                                    ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal**
```

What changes should I make to the code?

Comment: What language is this in?

Comment: The language used is Python

Comment: In most languages "\" is considered a special character. Usually you have to type "\\" to actually search for a backslash. See even on this site I can hardly use the backslash in the comment section...

Answer (score 0):

You could try replacing the "**\**" with  "**\\**" in general  "**\**" is used as escape character, thus to get the actual one being used, you need to use it two times.

Comment: Hey thank you for the immediate help. But that is not helping me. It is giving me the following error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script", line 99, in <module>
    line_map=re.sub("\\"," ",line_map)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/latest/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 151, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, 0).sub(repl, string, count)
  File "/grid/common/pkgs/python/latest/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: bogus escape (end of line)

Comment: Hey it worked!
I used the following code abc=abc.replace("\\","")